# Finding the following limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^{\ln{n}}}{(\ln{n})^{n}}\right)$

Tags: limits

I am having trouble proving the following limit evaluates to $0$:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^{\ln n}}{(\ln n)^n}\right)=0$$

I tried to use L'Hospital's rule, but couldn't do anything useful with it.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What did you get when you were working with l'Hopital's rule? That is what I would suggest using; it might be useful for you to learn if you made any mistakes in your computations.

Comment: Consider that $ln(n) < n \forall n \in \mathbb N$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\ln \left(\frac{n^{\ln{n}}}{(\ln{n})^{n}}\right)=\ln(n)^2-n \ln(\ln(n))= n\left[\frac{\ln(n)^2}{n}- \ln(\ln(n))\right]$$

It is easy to prove that this limit is $- \infty$.

Comment: Ahh okay, that helped a lot, thank you!